# UINavigationBar back button item font color won't set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicolor

I have a navigation bar on a viewController that I can enable/disable. **The problem is I can't get the font** for the `UIBarButtonItem`s to change colors after the view initially loads, though the back arrow will change.

I disable the `UINavigationBar` on **`myViewController`** with the following line of code:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

I have `UIControlState`s configured in **`AppDelegate.m`** for `UIBarButtonItem`s for enabled and disabled, but nothing happens to the font after the view initially loads.

In my `AppDelegate.m`, I have the following code to set the `UINavigationBar`'s font and color:

```
// UIBarButtonItem styling
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc]init];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// enabled
NSDictionary *enabledTextAttributeDictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor customCellHyperlinkColor], NSShadowAttributeName: shadow, NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:17.0]};

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:enabledTextAttributeDictionary forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// disabled
NSDictionary *disabledTextAttributeDictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor], NSShadowAttributeName: shadow, NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:17.0]};

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:disabledTextAttributeDictionary forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

// UINavigationBarTitle styling
NSDictionary *titleAttributeDictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor], NSShadowAttributeName: shadow, NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:19.0]};

[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil]setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributeDictionary];
```

I thought since I configured the 2 states (`UIControlStateNormal`/`UIControlStateDisabled`) in `AppDelegate.m`, nothing needs to be done other than enable/disable the `navigationBar`. Enable/disable does indeed enable/disable, but the color on the back button label doesn't change (though it does initially set to the color I set for `UIControlStateNormal` in `AppDelegate`).

I tried to manually set it, but the label on the backButtonItem stays blue while the icon to the left of it tints light gray. What (obvious thing) am I missing that is preventing me from changing the color of my back button font?

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

Comment: Thank you. The arrow tints, but the font color for the back button label doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor], NSFontAttributeName : place your font here}];
```

**instead of**

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Comment: I don't believe that's a valid line. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this
Add this code in you AppDelegate.m

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
   NSShadowAttributeName:shadow,
   NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]
   }
 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thank you. My concern is re: `UIControlStateDisabled`.